# GET AJAX - Json size trouble when quick updates

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I use AJAX to get "soft real time" values from a JSON file.

In fact on my server a C program is updating a Json file with some information (200ms period).
On my web page I get this Json file to display this information with a 250ms timer. I use Ajax to get the Json file.

The problem is when the Json file size changes, example :

My Json file was:

```
{ "data1": { "val1": "12", "val2": "125"}, "data2": { "val1": "253", "val2": "0"} }
```

And become :

```
{ "data1": { "val1": "12", "val2": "14"}, "data2": { "val1": "253", "val2": "0"} }
```

An error occurs, the response from the Ajax request is :

```
{ "data1": { "val1": "12", "val2": "14"}, "data2": { "val1": "253", "val2": "0"} }\u0
```

"\u0" seems to replace the missing character.

The same thing appears when the file becomes longer, the response is :

```
{ "data1": { "val1": "12", "val2": "14"}, "data2": { "val1": "253", "val2": "0"}
```

The last curly-bracket is missing.

My Javascript code for Ajax is :

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
    var xhr = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        } else {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support the XMLHTTPRequest object ...");
        return null;
    }
    return xhr;
}

function getDataAjax(callback, phpFile) {

    xhr = getXMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status == 0)) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open("GET", phpFile, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

The Json file is correct but the Ajax answer is not.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That poor server..... You really should be using Websockets

Comment: so what is the php file doing to return the response?

Comment: I'm not using a php file, I give directly the Json file, getDataAjax is just a generic function I also use it to request information from a php file.

Comment: i guess this is what you should expect from a system that gets and edits a file at the same time. You should try serving your JSON through a PHP (or whatever server language) file that locks the file first before getting its content. Maybe a little edit is necessary in the C edit script to handle that..

Comment: I thought about the gets and edit issue but when I don't reduce or increase the Json file, but only change values, I have no problem.

Comment: @deltaSim Well your code mentioned php in the URL so that was the assumption. Also GET requests cache so hopefully you set the right headers so implement cache busting.

Comment: i didn't mean to be condescending, hope you didn't think that ;). Are you absolutely sure that when you change values you will never get the beginning of an outdated file with the end of the updated one? The behaviour could also change depending on the type of server (assumption), that's why handling it yourself is probably better

Comment: @epascarello Hum ok, I will try cache busting but I don't see how it could solve my issue

Comment: @Kaddath No problem, I don't think that ;-) 
Yes I'm sure about it, I tested it during an hours with no problem if the size of the Json remains the same. But if the size changes I have an error, everytime.

Comment: @deltaSim ok so i guess we can assume that the error occurs because there is a little delay between the moment the response header is set (and so the content-length) and the actual file content is retreived. But i have no clue how to solve that apart from controlling it yourself in a script